# Watson Conversation - Retrieving specific data from nested context

Tags: json, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

I'd like the interaction to look like this:

- Bot: Name a country
- User: Mexico
- Bot: The population of Mexico is
  approximately 120M.

For now, I've got the populations hard-coded and looks like below:

```
{
  "context": {
    "inputcountry": "<?@Country?>",
    "populations": {
      "USA": "300M",
      "Mexico": "100M",
      "Japan": "127M"
    }
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "append": true,
      "values": [
        "The population of $inputcountry is approximately $populations.$inputcountry"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What is the syntax to provide the specific population number using the user input as the identifier/lookup?

Using $populations.$inputcountry shown above returns

```
{"USA": "300M","Mexico": "100M","Japan": "120M"}.Mexico
```

Comment: Why not try the results as entities?

Comment: Hi Athif, do you mean to have each country as it's own entity say @USA, @Mexico? And then multiple if condition responses? 

I'd like to avoid this because I just want one response to answer all countries. That way I just have to update the single lookup table in the context with 100 country:population pairs without creating 100 responses by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `<? $populations.get($inputcountry) ?>` - that should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Michal, so are you saying it's possible to actually do it this way on the online dialog config but I just need to keep trying, potentially with different syntax? The other respondents seem to suggest doing it manually with various entities/dialog nodes is the only way. 

Or are you suggesting 'try' as in it's not possible on the online config, but do it outside in say... javascript...etc.

Comment: Sorry, I have overlooked the expression didn't show in the answer. Fixed. Yes it is possible to do this by using .get method that is available on JsonObject that is an object used to represent complex JsonObjects on context.

Comment: Thanks for that! I knew the answer would be quite simple if it was possible. The resulting number is wrapped in quotations but I'll live. Just saved me a whooole lot of manual input and I can readily update the table too!

Comment: You can call .toInt() or .toDouble() to convert that to integer or double.

Comment: Hi,
I want to use a context variable in the response.
"responseText": "I am sorry I could not help you. You can contact our 24/7 Support on $supportNo or 'Create An Incident'. Choose an option below."
But this displays $supportNo instead of the actual value. What could be the issue?

Comment: Short hand syntax (`$supportNo`) is not supported in variable values. I would use the full syntax: `<? context.supportNo ?>` instead in the variable value. So:  `"responseText": "I am sorry I could not help you. You can contact our 24/7 Support on <? context.supportNo ?> or 'Create An Incident'."`

Answer (score 0):

You might have to write multiple dialogues for it..

```
 First dialogue triggering Condition: input.text.matches('USA') 
 Response: "The population of $input is approximately $populations.USA"


 Second dialogue triggering Condition: input.text.matches('Mexico')
 Response: "The population of $input is approximately $populations.Mexico"

Third dialogue triggering Condition: input.text.matches('Japan')
Response: "The population of $input is approximately $populations.Japan"
```

(Any dialog node can access context variables)

Another option would be to create Japan,USA,Mexico as entities.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems it's not possible doing it the way I was trying which definitely helps. I think I'll go with doing it manually.